# sending rc4 encrypted api call in java

Tags: java, php, encryption

I am trying to make an api call in java using these steps:

1. json encode
2. RC4 encryption
3. base64 encoding

I am currently using the same system in php and its working correctly:

```
$enc_request = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt(json_encode($request_params), "rc4", $this->_app_key));
```

But when I use the same system in java, the results are not as expected. Here's my code:

```
//json encoding
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("email", username);
obj.put("password", password);
obj.put("action", "login");

//function to encode base64
private String getBase64Encoded(String encryptedJsonString)
{
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedJsonString.getBytes());

    String encodedString = new String(encoded);

    return encodedString;
}

//function to encrypt in RC4
private String getRC4EncryptedString2(String string, String key) throws Exception
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
    SecretKeySpec rc4Key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "RC4");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rc4Key);

    byte[] cipherText = cipher.update(string.getBytes());

    return new String(cipherText);
}
```

I was able to identify the problem upto the RC4 encryption which is not returning the same result as the php version.

I've been battling this for 2 days now. I hope I have not missed any stupid thing because this should be straight-forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `byte[]` not a `String` to hold intermediate byte array values. A `String` is for text, not raw data, and will attempt to decode the bytes as character data using your system's default character set (at least, the single-parameter `String` constructor will). Same with `String.getBytes()`.

Just return `cipherText` directly from `getRC4EncryptedString2()`, and pass it directly to `getBase64Encoded()`. There's a reason those encoders operate on byte arrays, and that reason is *not* so that you can garble the data by applying a character encoding to it in between.

The same goes for the key you are passing to `getRC4EncryptedString2()`. At the bare minimum use `String.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` or something (assuming that your key is actually text and not yet another garbled byte array). The no-parameter version of `getBytes()` returns the text encoded using your system's default character set, which is not guaranteed to be what you want.

That also all applies to the `String` you are returning from your base 64 encoder. I don't know what base 64 encoder you are using, but make sure you specify the character set to the `String` constructor. Most likely you will be OK, purely by coincidence, but you should *always* specify a character set when converting to/from `String` and raw bytes. And that, of course, assumes that your base 64 encoder returns text, rather than bytes in the range 0-63.

The general point here is you can't just convert back and forth from `String` to `byte[]`. A `String` is for text and it's representation as a `byte[]` depends on the character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this using the following code. Hope this helps!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RC4Algo {

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, DecoderException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, JSONException
    {
        decryptRC4();
    }

    static String decryptRC4() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, JSONException{

        //byte[] plainBytes = "testString".getBytes();

        //json encoding
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("email", "username");
        obj.put("password", "password");
        obj.put("action", "login");

        byte [] plainBytes = obj.toString().getBytes();

        String hashedKey = hashedData("thisismysecretkey");

        //Generate a new key using KeyGenerator
        /*KeyGenerator rc4KeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
        SecretKey key = rc4KeyGenerator.generateKey();*/

        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(Hex.decode(hashedKey), "RC4");

        // Create Cipher instance and initialize it to encrytion mode
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");  // Transformation of the algorithm
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);

        String encoded = encodeBase64(cipherBytes);

        String decoded = decodeBase64(encoded);

        // Reinitialize the Cipher to decryption mode
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key, cipher.getParameters());
        byte[] plainBytesDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decode(decoded));

        System.out.println("Decrypted Data : "+new String(plainBytesDecrypted));
        return new String(plainBytesDecrypted);
    }

    static String decodeBase64(String encodedData){
        byte[] b = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedData);
        String decodedData = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(b);
        return decodedData;
    }

    static String encodeBase64(byte[] data){
        byte[] b = Base64.getEncoder().encode(data);
        String encodedData = new String(b);
        /*String encodedData = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(b);*/
        return encodedData;
    }

    static String hashedData(String key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        String password = key;

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(password.getBytes());

        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        //convert the byte to hex format method 1
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
         sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        //convert the byte to hex format method 2
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteData[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }

    }
```

Output:

[image]